# Mapping many to one with Scala and Slick

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I have a user who can have one more more LoginInfos. I wish to find this user by id and then pack each of the associated LoginInfos into the User object.

My expectation is that I will get a number of rows back equal to the number of LoginInfos each with the same user. Thus I first map the user into the object and then each of the LoginInfos. Is there a better way?

Here's what I have:

```
def find(userID: UUID) = {
val query = for {
  dbUser <- slickUsers.filter(_.id === userID.toString)
  dbUserLoginInfo <- slickUserLoginInfos.filter(_.userID === dbUser.id)
  dbLoginInfo <- slickLoginInfos.filter(_.id === dbUserLoginInfo.loginInfoId)
} yield (dbUser, dbLoginInfo)
db.run(query.result).map { results =>
      var loginList = List[LoginInfo]()
results.foreach {
  case (user, loginInfo) =>
    loginList = LoginInfo(loginInfo.providerID, loginInfo.providerKey) :: loginList
}
results.headOption.map {
  case (user, loginInfo) =>
    User(
      UUID.fromString(user.userID),
      loginList,
      user.firstName,
      user.lastName,
      user.fullName,
      user.email,
      user.avatarURL)
}
}
```

Comment: Why not filter `slickUsers` and then join `slickUserLoginInfos` and `slickLoginInfos`? I am not sure what query all those filters will return..

Comment: I made some changes to simplify matters.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def find(userID: UUID) = {

  val query = for {
    dbUser <- slickUsers.filter(_.id === userID.toString)
    dbUserLoginInfo <- slickUserLoginInfos if(_.userID === dbUser.id) // join would also work
    dbLoginInfo <- slickLoginInfos if(_.id === dbUserLoginInfo.loginInfoId)
  } yield (dbUser, dbLoginInfo)

  db.run(query.result).map { results =>
    val grouped = results.groupBy(_._1) // group by user, but it will be max 1, so it's ok..
    grouped.map {
      case (user, group) =>
        val loginInfo = group.map{ case (dbUser, dbLoginInfo) => LoginInfo(dbLoginInfo.providerID, dbLoginInfo.providerKey) }
        User(
          UUID.fromString(user.userID),
          loginInfo,
          user.firstName,
          user.lastName,
          user.fullName,
          user.email,
          user.avatarURL)
    }.headOption
  }
}
```

Check out my [blog post](http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html), I've done something similar.
Don't take it for granted, I don't have your table definitions, but it should work..

Comment: Why replace filter with if?

Comment: Maybe in this simple case your query will work properly, but that's not how you should do a [join in Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#joining-and-zipping).